# Connecting to SQL Server 2005 database in SQL Server Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-connection

I have installed `Microsoft SQL Server 2005`.

When I go to: `Start --> All Programs --> SQL Server Management Studio Express`

I don't get the `Connect` button highlighted and the `Server name` text box is empty.

How do I connect to the database with SQL Server Management Studio Express?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Sql server express:

First make sure that sql server service is actually running.

Try the following names for servername:

```
.
.\sqlexpress

localhost
localhost\sqlexpress
```

or: try to open the dropdownlist in servername and use `'<browse>'`

ps: the `.` is really a dot only

Comment: @Pleun. Thanks for your reply. Maybe the issue is in making sure that the sql server service is running. How can I make sure of that?

Comment: Start the sql server configuration manager (available from the start menu) and click on the services node

Comment: @Pleun. I just have `SQL Server Management Studio Express`. And, the folder that comes under `Microsoft SQL Server 2005` is `Configuration Tools` which contains `SQL Server Error and Usage Reporting`. I couldn't find what you mentioned, and don't know why I'm not getting what you told me to do. Thanks

Comment: You can also see the services in the general windows services configuration. (%SystemRoot%\system32\services.msc)

Comment: @Pleun. I saw the services, but `Microsoft SQL Server 2005` is not there!

Comment: Are you sure you installed the complete sql server and not only the management studio... There's no MSSQLSERVER service? What OS are you running?